# I've suddenly lost all my Gmail notes on my iMac Pro

Tags: imac, gmail, notes.app

I've suddenly lost all my Gmail notes on my iMac Pro. By lost, I mean I open the Apple notes app and see no items.

- I lost them on my iPhone last week and was unable to find a good documented process to follow to fix - so the notes do not sync with my iPhone today.
- I could still see them on my iMac Pro.

I decided to go and forward them to iCloud Note so I would never lose them again, [Here is the process I used to “forward them - please describe what you did or better - link to an online article explaining what process you followed]

Usually, they are in my email files (mail.app? A screenshot might help us help you here) and also show in the notes app.

How do I retrieve my critical Gmail notes?

Comment: Are the notes still in gmail web app? If so, you have a question how to delete the account and re-sync down from the cloud and possibly troubleshoot with that vendor (or us) when that sync breaks. If not, then you have a data recovery question and should choose how to get them back from Google in the cloud or from a local export backup. Rather than close this as unclear or too broad, would you edit this like I did to remove some of the “need help” and add some details?

Comment: You can always manually copy and paste your notes from google to iCloud